# working with long strings in lanterna Text GUI as INPUT/OUTPUT

Tags: java, lanterna

it try whith textbox like this:

```
 BasicWindow window = new BasicWindow();
 Panel contentPanel = new Panel(new GridLayout(1));
 contentPanel.addComponent(new Label("one line Textbox"));
 contentPanel.addComponent(
            new TextBox()
                    .setLayoutData(GridLayout.createHorizontallyFilledLayoutData(1)));
```

You can write long strings in it and you can't see them , when try to see them by this:

```
String result = new TextInputDialogBuilder()
    .setTitle("Multi-line editor")
    .setTextBoxSize(new TerminalSize(35, 5))
    .build()
    .showDialog(textGUI)
```

you can't copy/past  it. how can you see long strings in a big field and copy/past them?